# Unable to select fields in the grid Sencha Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a datagrid in my code and I am hoping to click through the text and copy it to clipboard but the app is not letting me copy it. Here is some code. Not sure how to enable selection.

```
Ext.define('xxxxx', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.xxxxxx',
requires: [
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.XTemplate',
    'Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer',
    ...
],
xtype : 'gridpanel',
viewConfig: {
    enableTextSelection : true
},
itemId: 'gridId',
ui: 'uipanel-default',
cls: 'uigridpanel-body uigridpanel-column someSummaryGridCls',
header: false,
```

The enableTextSelection field is set to true and still it doesn't work.

Some code from the DataGrid

```
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        columns: [{
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                draggable: false,
                itemId: 'iDColmn',
                width: '8%',
                autoSizeColumn: true,
                dataIndex: 'id',
                name: 'id',
                text: 'ID',
                tdCls: 'gridcellwrap',
                menuDisabled: true,
                stateId  : 'id'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                draggable: false,
                itemId: 'testColmn',
                width: '15%',
                tdCls: 'gridcellwrap',
                autoSizeColumn: true,
                dataIndex: 'test',
                name: 'test',
                text: 'Test',
                menuDisabled: true,
                stateId: 'test'
            },
```

Comment: Can you please share working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) ?

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to provide that. Are there any properties I should look for to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score -1):

You put "enableTextSelection" to the wrong place in your code. That config parameter is tied to columns, not to the grid view.

So, you must use it in your column objects starting with `xtype:"gridcolumn"`. You can enable text selection, for each column separately

Reference: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-enableTextSelection

Comment: I am downvotting because according to the docs, what you are stating is true, but if you alter the example in [docs gridcolumn](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html) you will find out that it is not working. But if you place it inside the `viewConfig` property of the grid it does work (for all the columns).